# Bootstrap grid style is ignoring offset

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a div like this which have is centered in the center of the main div. 
This div should have around 500px width. 
It looks like this: [image: test]

I want to use bootstrap grid so it will be responsive, but I'm having difficultness with those because the content appears in the same row. I tried to do it like this:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="row col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block"> GET DATIALS</a>
      <p class=" col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 line">
          Text 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 line">
        Text 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And css:

```
.line{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.delete{
  background-color: hsl(160, 0%, 18%) !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 47px;

}
```

For some reasons it isn't working and all appears in the same row and the offset columns are not taken in consideration. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the grid to work, you have to wrap your div's inside a `div` with a container `class` (see [bootstrap docs grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)). Also, bootstrap is mobile first meaning that if you specify a given `col-xs-*` this `class` will propagate up to the bigger column classes so if you need the same number of columns in all xs, sm, md and lg you only need to specify xs.

**Live demo:**
http://www.bootply.com/QztQES4NTI

**Markup**

```
<div class="center text-center container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 ">
    <!-- I added btn-primary but feel free to remove it if not needed -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"> GET DATIALS</a>
        <p class=" col-xs-3"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-4">
        <div class="col-xs-2 line">
            Text 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 line">
            Text 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 ">
            Text 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I started looking at your code and I ended up doing this and got really close to what you wanted. The thing with bootstrap is this: you have to have a `div` for the row then a `div` for the col. size here is the HTML, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block">GET DETAILS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center text">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 line">
          Text 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 line">
          Text 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
          Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```